# Pandas Merge Columns with Priority

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input dataframe;

```
    MinA  MinB   MaxA  MaxB
0   1     2      5     7
1   1     0      8     6
2   2            15    15
3         3                   
4                      10
```

I want to merge "min" and "max" columns amongst themselves with priority (A columns have more priority than B columns).

If  both columns are null, they should have default values, for min=0 for max=100.

Desired output is;

```
    MinA MinB  MaxA MaxB      Min  Max
0   1     2      5     7      1    5
1   1     0      8     6      1    8
2   2            15    15     2    15
3         3                   3    100
4                      10     0    10
```

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html). With your data that would look like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'MinA': [1,1,2,None,None],
    'MinB': [2,0,None,3,None],
    'MaxA': [5,8,15,None,None],
    'MaxB': [7,6,15,None,10],
})

# Create new Column, using A as the base, if it is Nan, then use B.
# Then do the same again using specified values
df['Min'] = df['MinA'].mask(pd.isna, df['MinB']).mask(pd.isna, 0)
df['Max'] = df['MaxA'].mask(pd.isna, df['MaxB']).mask(pd.isna, 100)
```

The above would result in the desired output:

```
    MinA    MinB    MaxA    MaxB    Min     Max
0   1       2       5       7       1       5
1   1       0       8       6       1       8
2   2       NaN     15      15      2       15
3   NaN     3       NaN     NaN     3       100
4   NaN     NaN     NaN     10      0       10
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use fillna() will be fine.

```
df['Min'] = df['MinA'].fillna(df['MinB']).fillna(0)
df['Max'] = df['MaxA'].fillna(df['MaxB']).fillna(100)
```